# Google Sheets: MIN() Returns a #DIV/0! Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, min, divide-by-zero

I'm having issues with functions like MIN(), MAX(), AVERAGE() etc, when a few cells have no value. They return the error #DIV/0!

Most 'solutions' seem to be to resort to IFERROR, but that's pretty useless - why return nothing when just a few cells out of thousands are empty?

I don't understand why such simple native functions cannot cope with blank cells, let alone why MIN() would return #DIV/0! when no division is used.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet or some sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a formula like:

```
=MIN(A1:A10)
```

and that formula returns `#DIV/0!`, then at least one cell in the range has a zero-divide error. *(same is true for Excel)*

Fix the error

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue - didn't spot it with ~2000 rows. Fixed by adding iferror within the ArrayFormula:

= ArrayFormula( iferror( degrees( acos( (power(F3:F2005,2) + power(M3:M2005,2) - power(G3:G2005 ,2) ) / ( 2 * F3:F2005 * M3:M2005 ) ) )))

Comment: @maxhugen  Good Job !